# error: no matching function for call to 'begin(long double [nPoints])' ; initializing vector with a hardcoded int versus an integer variable

Tags: c++, std

I wrote a code that worked with magic numbers, and now I am trying to place the magic numbers into variables.  Essentially, I create an array with a fixed number of elements, I fill the array, and then I convert it to a vector.  This works, as long as I create the array as:

```
long double yy[5];
vector<long double> YY;
YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
```

but the array conversion breaks if I create the array as:

```
int nPoints = 5;
long double yy[nPoints];
vector<long double> YY;
YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
```

I have tried converting the nPoints to other data types, checking to make sure it is the data type that I assigned it, etc., but I haven't had any luck.

```
// non functional code
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int nPoints = 5;

    // initialize an input vector
    vector<long double> xx = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // compute some function of xx in a loop
    long double yy[nPoints];
    for(int i = 0; i<=nPoints - 1; i++){
        yy[i] = 2*xx[i];
    }

    // convert yy from an array to a vector
    vector<long double> YY;
    YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));

    for(int i = 0; i<=nPoints -1; i++){
        cout<<YY[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And Working Code

```
// Working Code: simply changed long double yy[nPoints] to long double yy[5]

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int nPoints = 5;

    // initialize an input vector
    vector<long double> xx = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // compute some function of xx in a loop
    long double yy[5];
    for(int i = 0; i<=nPoints - 1; i++){
        yy[i] = 2*xx[i];
    }

    // convert yy from an array to a vector
    vector<long double> YY;
    YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));

    for(int i = 0; i<=nPoints -1; i++){
        cout<<YY[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first returns the following error message:

```
g++ -Wall testMain.cpp
testMain.cpp: In function 'int main()':
testMain.cpp:20:32: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(long double [nPoints])'
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:36,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\initializer_list:89:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::begin(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)'
   89 |     begin(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\initializer_list:89:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:32: note:   mismatched types 'std::initializer_list<_Tp>' and 'long double*'
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:48:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&)'
   48 |     begin(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
      |     ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:48:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:32: note:   variable-sized array type 'long double [nPoints]' is not a valid template argument
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:58:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&)'
   58 |     begin(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
      |     ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:58:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:32: note:   variable-sized array type 'long double [nPoints]' is not a valid template argument
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:87:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, long long unsigned int _Nm> constexpr _Tp* std::begin(_Tp (&)[_Nm])'
   87 |     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
      |     ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:87:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:32: note:   variable-sized array type 'long long int' is not a valid template argument
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:104:31: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> _Tp* std::begin(std::valarray<_Tp>&)'
  104 |   template<typename _Tp> _Tp* begin(valarray<_Tp>&);
      |                               ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:104:31: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:32: note:   mismatched types 'std::valarray<_Tp>' and 'long double [nPoints]'
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:105:37: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> const _Tp* std::begin(const std::valarray<_Tp>&)'
  105 |   template<typename _Tp> const _Tp* begin(const valarray<_Tp>&);
      |                                     ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:105:37: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:32: note:   mismatched types 'const std::valarray<_Tp>' and 'long double [nPoints]'
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                ^
testMain.cpp:20:41: error: no matching function for call to 'end(long double [nPoints])'
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:36,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\initializer_list:99:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::end(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)'
   99 |     end(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
      |     ^~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\initializer_list:99:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:41: note:   mismatched types 'std::initializer_list<_Tp>' and 'long double*'
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:68:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&)'
   68 |     end(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
      |     ^~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:68:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:41: note:   variable-sized array type 'long double [nPoints]' is not a valid template argument
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:78:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&)'
   78 |     end(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
      |     ^~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:78:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:41: note:   variable-sized array type 'long double [nPoints]' is not a valid template argument
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:97:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, long long unsigned int _Nm> constexpr _Tp* std::end(_Tp (&)[_Nm])'
   97 |     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
      |     ^~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:97:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:41: note:   variable-sized array type 'long long int' is not a valid template argument
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:106:31: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> _Tp* std::end(std::valarray<_Tp>&)'
  106 |   template<typename _Tp> _Tp* end(valarray<_Tp>&);
      |                               ^~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:106:31: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:41: note:   mismatched types 'std::valarray<_Tp>' and 'long double [nPoints]'
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
      |                                         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\string:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from testMain.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:107:37: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> const _Tp* std::end(const std::valarray<_Tp>&)'
  107 |   template<typename _Tp> const _Tp* end(const valarray<_Tp>&);
      |                                     ^~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\9.1.0\bits\range_access.h:107:37: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testMain.cpp:20:41: note:   mismatched types 'const std::valarray<_Tp>' and 'long double [nPoints]'
   20 |  YY.insert(YY.begin(), begin(yy), end(yy));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem 1

You are missing the header file that declares [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin).

Add

```
#include <iterator>
```

to your file.

#### Problem 2

```
long double yy[nPoints];
```

is not standard C++. It is supported by some compilers as an extension.

`std::begin` does not work with VLAs. It works only with standards arrays -- arrays whose sizes are known at compile time.

---

Given that you can use `std::vector` for arrays whose sizes are known at run time, there is no need to use a VLA.

Instead of

```
long double yy[nPoints];
```

use

```
std::vector<long double> yy(nPoints);
```

Comment: @BrianBurrows -- go ahead. I'll be glad to respond if the answers are simple. If the answers are not simple, then this is not the right place to address them.

Comment: When you use a standard library function, always lookup the standards (or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language) for the header file that is supposed to declare that function. Use that header file always.

Comment: Don't rely on a header file being `#include`d indirectly.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, but I do have a few questions.

As to problem 1: I think I am a bit confused by when I need to include things that seem to be in the standard library; For instance, begin(yy) works without #include <iterator> in the working code that I posted above.

As to problem 2, I didn't realize that using [] creates a variable length array and using () creates a sized array?  However, even if that is the case, wouldn't the code break when using 

    ```
    long double yy[5];
    ```

Comment: @BrianBurrows `long double yy[nPoints];` creates a VLA only because the value of `nPoints` will be not known until run time. `long double yy[5];` does not create a VLA since the size of the array is known at compile time.

Comment: @BrianBurrows Standard library headers *sometimes* include other headers, but most of the time that's up to the implementation and is not guaranteed by the standard, so you shouldn't rely on it. Always include the relevant header files yourself. `long double yy[nPoints]` creates a variable-length array not because of the `[]`, but because `nPoints` is not a compile-time constant expression. It's a variable initialized by a constant expression, but you didn't explicitly mark the variable `const` or `constexpr`. In standard C++, the value between the brackets has to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @BrianBurrows Vectors are a completely different thing. They allocate the memory dynamically and manage it for you automatically, so they can handle variable lengths just fine.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Thank you for the additional clarification!